# Return matching posts based on postmeta meta_key

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

So I have the following SQL tables and their all matching:

```
wp_postmeta   
wp_posts   
wp_1_postmeta   
wp_1_posts   
wp_2_postmeta   
wp_2_posts
```

Then I'm using the following SQL query to search and return all `meta_key` matching `"_taleo_id"` inside the `wp_..._postmeta tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id'
union all
SELECT *
FROM wp_1_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id'
union all
SELECT *
FROM wp_2_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_taleo_id'
```

I get the following results back:

[image]

So now since I have the matching `post_id` based on the `meta_key`, how can I look inside the `wp_posts` or `wp_1_posts` table and return the `post` matching the `post_id`?

**Example**:
In the above screenshot, we have a matching `meta_key` that has a `post_id` of 252, now if I jump into the `wp_posts` table, I'll see the following result shown below - So I'm basically wanting to print out all the posts that have a matching meta_key of taleo id all in one view.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have multiple post and meta tables?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this is how WordPress multi-sites work, it's multiple websites so it uses a `wp_1_posts, or wp_2_postmeta` prefix, I'm basically wanting to print out all the posts from all of our websites in a view that have a matching taleo_id.

Comment: You can't use a central database for all the sites?  In any case, I've answered below, but it seems strange to divide the data into three -- particularly if you want to analyze it as a single source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM wp_postmeta pm join
     wp_posts p
     on p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_taleo_id'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.*
FROM wp_1_postmeta pm join
     wp_1_posts p
     on p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_taleo_id'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.*
FROM wp_2_postmeta pm join
     wp_2_posts p
     on p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_taleo_id';
```

I don't understand why you have multiple posts and metadata tables.  It seems unusual.